# How to add multi-parameterized unit tests in the same test class

Tags: android, junit

I have a java class in my android app that contains two or more methods that accept a different collection of parameters. How to write a test class containing multi-parameterized unit tests ?

hint: the problem is that when i write the test class with annotation @RunWith(Parameterized.class), it only accepts one parameterized unit test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few options for running tests with different sets of parameters.

### JUnit Parameterized

You could use different test classes inside another class with the [Enclosed runner](http://junit.org/javadoc/latest/org/junit/experimental/runners/Enclosed.html).

```
@RunWith(Enclosed.class)
public class TestClass {

    @RunWith(Parameterized.class)
    public static class FirstParameterizedTest {

        @Parameters
        public static Object[][] data() {
            ...
        }

        @Test
        public void someTest() {
            ...
        }
    }

    public static class SecondParameterizedTest {

        @Parameters
        public static Object[][] data() {
            ...
        }

        @Test
        public void anotherTest() {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

### JUnitParams

[JUnitParams](http://pragmatists.github.io/JUnitParams/) has plenty of ways for specifying the parameters. See https://github.com/Pragmatists/JUnitParams/blob/master/src/test/java/junitparams/usage/SamplesOfUsageTest.java

Here is a simple example.

```
@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)
public class TestClass {

    @Test
    @Parameters({"AAA,1", "BBB,2"})
    public void paramsInAnnotation(String p1, Integer p2) {
        ...
    }
}
```

### Burst

Burst uses Enums for specifying test parameters. Different test methods can use different Enums.

```
@RunWith(BurstJUnit4.class)
public class TestClass {
    enum FirstSetOfParameters {
        A(1,2),
        B(2,3)

        final int x1, x2;

        FirstSetOfParameters( int x1, int x2) {
            this.x1=x1;
            this.x2=x2;
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void firstTest( FirstSetOfParameters parameters) {
        ...
    }

    enum SecondSetOfParameters {
        A(1),
        B(2)

        final int x1;

        SecondSetOfParameters(int x1) {
            this.x1=x1;
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void secondTest(SecondSetOfParameters parameters) {
        ...
    }
}
```

### Other libraries

There are some more libraries. You may have a look at [Zohhak](http://piotrturski.github.io/zohhak/) and [junit-dataprovider](https://github.com/TNG/junit-dataprovider).